# How to select this child element in JSOUP

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I somehow can't get this element:

[image]

This is what I tried:

```
Elements flightNrElement = e1.select("td.carrier > span:nth-child(2)");
fl_nr = flightNrElement.text();
```

Would apreciate your help! BR!

Comment: td.carrier > span:eq(2) The html would help me to test before answer

Comment: @user1121883: `eq` is 0-based.

Comment: http://www.kayak.de/flights/MUC-TXL/2015-01-30?pn=0 here is the URL. Thanks so far. eq(1) didn't work for me

Comment: I can't find something similar in your link

Comment: I was having trouble doing the same. I found that you need to go to one flight (not the first one, its train "deutsche Bahn"). Expand this menu and then View source. I am new to this. Can someone explain to me what happens there? And best, tell me how to get the flight number in there. Thank you user1121883 so far

Comment: I suggest you do a System.out.println(doc.html()) and make sure the html you are parsing is the same to the one you have in browser

Comment: I already did a checkup concerning this. My comment from before states the problem I have with this. Thanks!!

Edit: It seems to be buried under a javascript (?) element. While i can grab things like price and airline which is in plain sight, I need to collapse the menu underneath the flight. How can I handle this with jSoup?

Comment: this means that part is loaded after using ajax; afaik you can't do this using only jsoup (add something that is able to run the javasctipt and emulate a click: htmlunit.sourceforge.net )

Comment: Thanks, I got no experience with this at all, but ill give it a try.

Comment: Another option here is to examine the AJAX call of interest, recreate it and then run jsoup over the response

Comment: open the website in google-chrome, press f12 to inspect element. click on the magnifier then click on the tag u want to extract. at the bottom nice little script shows up that u can simply copy and paste in ur jsoup parser

Comment: thanks nafas. I tried the inspect thing before. I can't see where the script is displayed you are talking about. What i saw was eg the CSS path of my elemtent being: #inlineflightitinerary0 > table > tbody > tr.first > td.carrier > span:nth-child(2)